# Can't get an instance of an inherited class

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, casting

I'm working with Cocos2D and I've made a very simple class that inherits from `CCSprite`. I have the following class method:

```
+(id)carWithFile:(NSString *)fileName{
Car *car= (Car*)[CCSprite spriteWithFile:fileName];
car.anchorPoint=ccp(0,0);
    NSLog(@"%@",[car class]);//Here I get CCSprite in the console
return car;
}
```

But to my surprise, I still get a `CCSprite` instance when I call this method. Even when I check in the method itself, the class of the newly created object is `CCSprite` instead of `Car`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a subclass from car you can use

```
[Car spriteWithFile:fileName];
```

Comment: But it will return CCSprite, not a Car.

Comment: In your question you cast it to car but you do not use your Car class to alloc/init it.

Comment: It's very odd. I tried [Car spriteWithFile:fileName] and this time it worked.+1 for your help but I'm still curious why the way I was doing did not work. Would very appreciate if someone could explain it.

Comment: spriteWithFile: will return an id - i am not sure but i assume the folowing: an id factory method will return the class it is implemented in